# Posting to my Facebook timeline from C#

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, oauth, dotnetopenauth

Can someone please provide me with the workflow required to be able to simply post a message to my Facebook page? From what I have read, DotNetOpenAuth 4.1 does not support Facebook's OAuth 2.0 protocol? If someone has a better suggestion for an OAuth2 library, I'd like to hear it and if you can provide an example of how to post a message to a Facebook page, that'd be great!

Also, this is a Winforms application, not a Web Application.

Comment: Try this link, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720023/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-getting-started

Comment: You can use the [facebook-csharp-sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk) (also available through NuGet). (After obtaining the access tokens it's pretty straightforward)

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample) a working C#/WinForms sample.

Comment: Guys these are all good, but should it be this complicated? Keep in mind this is my own facebook page. Can I [Authenticate As an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) and have an access key that lasts forever? Once I have that key, isn't there like 10 lines of code that uses [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to post a message to my wall?

Comment: Why not try a http POST to graph.facebook.com with the access token. Though I'm not familiar with C#.

Comment: I did. I'm getting a 403 - Forbidden response back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 clients are simple enough to write that you almost don't need a library.  Try following the Facebook documentation yourself using HTTP calls in your winforms app and see if you can get it to work.

For client apps like winforms, the trickiest part can sometimes be that there isn't an obvious redirect URL.

DotNetOpenAuth 4.x does support Facebook (by implementing workarounds for FB's non-compliance with the spec).

Answer (score 0):

I generally use ComputerBeacon Libarary. It is quite fluent

http://computerbeacon.net/library/facebookgraphtoolkit